# Chech Username(Email) Availability with LiveValidation.Custom Function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with checking for e-mail availability with the custom function of LiveValidation: it keeps sending back that the e-mail is already in use even if it isn't.

Can someone please help me out of this ?

-- EDIT--

I figured out that the function `check_availability` can't return the true or false from the Ajax call. So I'm almost there I just need to make the function return the right bool value.

This is my code until now:

JS File:

```
//function to check username availability  
    var check_availability = function(){  

        //get the username  
        var email = $('#email').val();  

        //use ajax to run the check  
        $.post("checkEmail.php", { email: email },  
            function(result){  
                //if the result is 1  
                if(result == 1){  
                    //show that the username is available  
                    return true;
                }else{  
                    //show that the username is NOT available  
                    return false;  
                }  
        }); 
// Validation 
var mail =  new LiveValidation('email', { validMessage: "Ok!" });
mail.add( Validate.Custom,{failureMessage:"E-mail is al in gebruik!", 
                 against: function(){ return check_availability() }
                 });
```

`checkEmail.php` file:

```
<?php
require_once 'db_config.php';
//Controleren of e-mail adress al in gebruik is     

$sql_select_email = "SELECT email from tblUsers WHERE email = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'";
            if (($result_select_email = mysql_query($sql_select_email)) === false) 
            {
                # als de query fout is -> foutafhandeling
                echo showSQLError($sql_select_email,mysql_error(),'Fout bij het opvragen van de gegevens.');
            }
            else
            {
                //Query gelukt
                $count_email = mysql_num_rows($result_select_email);
                if($count_email > 0)
                {
                    // Not available
                    echo 0; 
                }
                else
                {
                    // Available
                    echo 1; 
                }
            }
?>
```

Comment: the 'return' lines only return from the anonymous function after $.post gets its response. your check_availability function doesnt appear to return anything, but then i can't tell where its supposed to end because you dont have the final }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
//function to check username availability  
check_availability = function(){  

    //get the username  
    var email = $('#email').val();

    //declare the return value for the $.post call
    var return_value = null;

    // make the $.post call synchronous  !!important
    $.ajaxSetup({async: false});

    //use ajax to run the check  
    $.post("checkEmail.php", { email: email },  
        function(result){  
            //if the result is 1  
            if(result == 1){  
                //show that the username is available  
                return_value = true;
            }else{  
                //show that the username is NOT available  
                return_value = false;  
            }  
    }); 

    // return the result (true or false)
    return return_value;

// Validation 
var mail =  new LiveValidation('email', { validMessage: "Ok!" });
mail.add( Validate.Custom,{failureMessage:"E-mail is al in gebruik!", 
             against: function(){ return check_availability() }
             });
```

This should work.  I tested it.  sort of... ha!

The problem was that you cannot return a value from within the scope of the $.post call.  You must first declare the return variable outside the scope of the $.post call. Then you can assign the value of that variable from within the $.post.  But also the $.post call must be set to "synchronous". ie - `$.ajaxSetup({async: false});`

Comment: Thx finally there :p
But there were some fault in the code you pasted but it putted me in the good direction ... 
I tried the global variable too before but it didn't worked because i didn't set asyn to false but THANK YOU anyway :)

Comment: oops.  ok I fixed the errors in the code..  re-paste it and try it now.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how the LiveValidation plugin works, but the check_availability() function now should be working correctly, returning true or false from the result of checkEmail.php.  Carry on. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, ajax result would be a string. result == "1" not result == 1.

You could also do result == parseFloat(result)

Comment: Tried but still got the same fault.